# BPY render using "Blender_eevee" can not work

Tags: python, rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, linux

I'm using bpy python module in Ubuntu 20.04, I try to render picture using `engine='BLENDER_EEVEE'` engine as shown below.

```
bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'BLENDER_EEVEE'
#bpy.context.space_data.params.filename = "test4.png"
bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = self.img_body
bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.file_format = 'PNG'
bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
```

Then I got the following error

> Unable to find 'wl_proxy_marshal_flags' in 'libwayland-client.so.0'.

However, when I set `engine='CYCLES'`, it worked fine, but it took too much time.
I searched for a long time but didn't find a proper answer to fix this problem.

Comment: what blender version are you using? try using the latest version 3.6.

Comment: I don't use the blender application, only the python module 'bpy' version 3.6.0.

Comment: how did you install the bpy module? pip?

Comment: yes, and I tried 3.4.0, 3.5.0 and 3.60. All of them didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me.

The error `Unable to find 'wl_proxy_marshal_flags' in 'libwayland-client.so.0'.` occured because on Ubuntu 20.04, libwayland-client0 version is 1.18, and `wl_proxy_marshal_flags` is introduced in version 1.20, which can not be accessed on Ubuntu 20.04, you can only have libwayland-client0 version 1.20 on Ubuntu 22.04.

So a quick solution to this problem is to upgrade your Ubuntu to a newer version such as 22.04.
If upgrade OS is not an option then I guess you can try to compile libwayland-client0 1.20 from source.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I add "apt-get install libegl1" in the Dockerfile, which solves the problem. But I'll try your method later.